# How to use Cypress for validating form fields and handling errors in Angular (version 13.3.0)

Tags: angular, validation, testing, cypress

I'm new to Cypress and I'm working with Angular version 13.3.0. I'm trying to validate a form where, upon clicking a button, the form opens, and it has various validation rules, such as 'First Name is required', along with other fields like 'Last Name', 'Gender', 'User Type', 'Username', and 'Password'.

The validation errors are currently showing in the browser, and I'd like to use Cypress to check and handle these errors. Can someone guide me on how to use Cypress commands, especially 'should', to validate these form fields and handle any validation errors that may arise?

```
describe('Form Validation', () => {
  it('Should validate form fields and handle errors', () => {
    cy.visit('http://qa.aquators.com');


    // Fill out the form
    cy.get('[data-cy="firstname"]').type('');
    cy.get('[data-cy="lastname"]').type('');
    // cy.get('input[data-cy="male"]').click({ force: true });
    // cy.get('input[data-cy="finance_manager"]').click({ force: true });
    cy.get('[data-cy="username"]').type('');
    cy.get('[data-cy="password"]').type('');

    // Submit the form
    cy.get('[btn-id="submit"]').click(); 
    // Check validation errors
    cy.get('[data-cy="firstname-error"]').should('contain', 'First Name is required');
    cy.get('[data-cy="lastname-error"]').should('contain', 'Last Name is required');
    cy.get('[data-cy="gender-error"]').should('contain', 'Gender is required');
    cy.get('[data-cy="usertype-error"]').should('contain', 'User Type is required');
    cy.get('[data-cy="username-error"]').should('contain', 'Username is required');
    cy.get('[data-cy="password-error"]').should('contain', 'Password is required');

    // Handle validation errors as needed
  });
});
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving when trying to run this code? What does the HTML of your page look like?

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `validationMessage` property by chaining the "connector" query `.its('validationMessage')`.

Normally, `.should('contain', ...something)` is used straight after the element query when there some text between the tags, like `<div>Some text is here</div>`.

But `<input>` elements store the value you typed in using the `value` property, and the error message in the `validationMessage` property.

The `it('some-property')` command is used to ***change the subject*** from the element to the `some-property` value.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="firstname-error"]')
  .its('validationMessage')
  .should('contain', 'First Name is required')

cy.get('[data-cy="lastname-error"]')
  .its('validationMessage')
  .should('contain', 'Last Name is required')

cy.get('[data-cy="gender-error"]')
  .its('validationMessage') 
  .should('contain', 'Gender is required')

cy.get('[data-cy="usertype-error"]')
  .its('validationMessage')
  .should('contain', 'User Type is required')

cy.get('[data-cy="username-error"]')
  .its('validationMessage')
  .should('contain', 'Username is required')

cy.get('[data-cy="password-error"]')
  .its('validationMessage')
  .should('contain', 'Password is required')
```

As a side note, you can incorporate the property inside the `.should()` as well:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="password-error"]')
  .should('have.property', 'validationMessage', 'Password is required')
```

This is an ***exact*** check,  contrast to `contains` which is a ***partial*** check.